# console log using selenium certain messages are getting truncated abruptly

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to validate the browser console messages via selenium api certain messages are getting truncated abruptly and all these messages begin with some icon.

So for example expected messages is this “xyz-ENa50707a1661440e4a3070d8206797cf4.min.js?cb=1523503349:15 icon Rule "xyz" fired.”  but what i am getting is "“xyz-ENa50707a1661440e4a3070d8206797cf4.min.js?cb=1523503349:15 icon".

my code is like

```
LogEntries logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
       logEntries.getAll();
        for (LogEntry entry : logEntries) {

            System.out.println(new Date(entry.getTimestamp()) + " " + entry.getLevel() + " " + entry.getMessage());
   }
```

Any suggestion.

even System.setOut(printStream); not able capture full string in message.

Comment: which library are you using for log generation?

Comment: I would suggest you to use log4j for logging purpose.

Comment: DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();   LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
 logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);

Comment: @cruisepandey I want to fetch log not print? Hope that is clear. code i posted it is able to print but after certain character, the string is just truncated. any pointers appreciated.

Comment: did you figure this out, Raj?  I have a similar problem and I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Anybody found the solution for this?